# array of structs created with malloc is not deleting nor resizing last element using free and realloc

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc, free

My code consist in a aplication which receive by console one client (`clientes`) and add it into an array created with malloc. After we can remove this cliente. Also we can add a new travel (`viajes`) and remove it (process is analog to showed in code).

I am trying to remove last item of an array of struct created with malloc, as I said earlier. I will show you the code (how I add a new `clientes` and how i try to delete it). Also say that errors I get are commented in the line which produce the error, so I think it is more visual. Also say the code is MCVE, so only copying code will run. The code is of my aplication is:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

// DEFINE STRUCTS
struct viaje {
    char *identificador;
    char *ciudadDestino;
    char *hotel;
    int numeroNoches;
    char *tipoTransporte;
    float precioAlojamiento;
    float precioDesplazamiento;
};

struct cliente {
    char *dni;
    char *nombre;
    char *apellidos;
    char *direccion;
    int totalViajes;
    struct viaje *viajes;
};

int main(){
    // Variables
    int i = 0;
    int totalClientes = 0;
    char dni[255];
    char nombre[255];
    char apellidos[255];
    char direccion[255];

    // Init array of struct cliente (in var clientes)
    struct cliente *clientes = (struct cliente *)malloc(0);

    printf("Input number of elements of struct clientes: ");
    scanf("%i", &totalClientes);
    fflush(stdin);

    // ADDING NEW ELEMENTS INTO CLIENTES
    for (i = 0; i < totalClientes; i++) {

        // Receive parameters
        printf("Input NIF: ");
        gets(dni);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Input NAME: ");
        gets(nombre);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Input SURNAME: ");
        gets(apellidos);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Input ADDRESS: ");
        gets(direccion);
        fflush(stdin);

        // Create memory for his child (MAX_TAM_* are #define int)
        clientes = (struct cliente *)realloc(clientes, (i+1)*sizeof(struct cliente));
        clientes[i].dni = (char *)malloc(200*sizeof(char));
        clientes[i].nombre = (char *)malloc(200*sizeof(char));
        clientes[i].apellidos = (char *)malloc(200*sizeof(char));
        clientes[i].direccion = (char *)malloc(200*sizeof(char));
        clientes[i].viajes = (struct viaje *)malloc(0); // Init clientes[i].viajes to 0 as previously done with clientes

        // Adding received element
        strcpy(clientes[i].dni, dni);
        strcpy(clientes[i].nombre, nombre);
        strcpy(clientes[i].apellidos, apellidos);
        strcpy(clientes[i].direccion, direccion);
    /* DANGER - ERROR HERE */
        clientes[i].totalViajes = 0; // HERE I GET A NOT EXPECTED BEHAVIOR - int is not added to clientes[i].totalViajes - Receive NULL
        // New element added sucessfully
    }

    // SHOW ELEMENTS CREATED
    for (i = 0; i < totalClientes; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        printf("%i.\n", i);
        printf("NIF: %s\n", clientes[i].dni);
        printf("NAME: %s\n", clientes[i].nombre);
        printf("SURNAME: %s\n", clientes[i].apellidos);
        printf("ADDRESS: %s\n", clientes[i].direccion);
        printf("TRAVELS_COUNT: %s\n", clientes[i].totalViajes);
       printf("\n");
    }

    // DELETING AN ELEMENT OF CLIENTES
    int posCliente = 0;

    printf("Input position of struct clientes that you wanna delete: ");
    // posCliente is the position (inside the array) of cliente we wanna remove
    scanf("%i", &posCliente);
    fflush(stdin);

    // Rewind one position array clientes since cliente we want to remove
    for (i = posCliente; i < totalClientes-1; i++) {
        // Rewind one element array clientes
        clientes[i] = clientes[i+1];
    }

    //freeing memory of this element (now, the element is the last of the array, we have moved it into last position with previously for)
    free(clientes[totalClientes].dni);
    free(clientes[totalClientes].nombre);
    free(clientes[totalClientes].apellidos);
    free(clientes[totalClientes].direccion);
    clientes[totalClientes].totalViajes = 0;
    // Remove / free memory of the element deleted
/* DANGER - ERROR HERE */
    //free(clientes[totalClientes]); // HERE I GET AN ERROR: `error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'free'`

    // Now totalClientes is one less (we have deleted one element)
    totalClientes--;

    // Resize array clientes. It must have one less element (now totalClientes is totalClientes-1)
/* DANGER - ERROR HERE */
    //clientes = (struct cliente *)realloc(clientes, (totalClientes)*sizeof(struct cliente)); // HERE I DO NOT GET AN ERROR BUT PROGRAM CRASH

    // SHOW ELEMENTS AFTER DELETING
/* DANGER - ERROR HERE */
    // if the max legnth is totalClientes+1 we can see that the last element removed with free cointinues existing, so free is not freeing memory well
    for (i = 0; i < totalClientes; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        printf("%i.\n", i);
        printf("NIF: %s\n", clientes[i].dni);
        printf("NAME: %s\n", clientes[i].nombre);
        printf("SURNAME: %s\n", clientes[i].apellidos);
        printf("ADDRESS: %s\n", clientes[i].direccion);
        printf("TRAVELS_COUNT: %s\n", clientes[i].totalViajes);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't try to free the last element, just realloc the array down one.

Comment: @MartinJames but is needed to free the memory earlier delete last element, isn't it? However, when I try to resize array, program crash without error, so I do not Know what is happening

Comment: A global variable `i` is a bad idea, especially in a single-function program.  Doubly so when it is used as a loop control variable inside `main()`.

Comment: yeah, I know, it is only one example functional of my code. In my original code `i` is local, no global

Comment: Note the constraints on [Using `fflush(stdin)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Then, how can I delete buffer in? .  What does fflush have to do with the proposed problems? Do you have any relationship? I say it because I do not understand what can influence one thing in the other. Thank you.

Comment: There is no clientes[totalClientes].  The array size only goes from 0 thru totalClientes-1.

Comment: @JuMoGar `fflush(stdin);` leads to undefined behavior, thus making it impossible to reason about what your program is doing. Once UB is in, all bets are off.

Comment: You are moving data one position down, this means that positions `totalClientes` and `totalClientes-1` have same malloced pointers that you're freeing... but that you shouldn't...

Comment: Using `fflush` on `stdin` is a common (bad) practice for MS-OS's. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz.aspx.

Comment: @unwind: if they're working on Windows, then `fflush(stdin)` has a meaning defined by Microsoft, not by the C standard.

Comment: Note, too, that [`gets()` is too dangerous to be used — ever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used).  Again (see next comment), this isn't directly the cause of your trouble; it is an issue of which you should be aware.

Comment: I didn't say "`fflush(stdin)` is the cause of your trouble"; I simply pointed you to where you can find a discussion on the limits on where it can be used.  If you're using `gets()`, there won't be any stray data in the input buffer; it reads up to and including the newline.  There will be a newline in the input buffer after the first `scanf()` for the number of clients; that needs to be consumed before you start reading lines.  There are other ways than using `fflush(stdin)` to do that — see the x-ref.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several issues here.  First:

```
printf("TRAVELS_COUNT: %s\n", clientes[i].totalViajes);
```

The field `totalViajes` is an integer but you're using `%s` to print, which expects a `char *` pointing to a null terminated string.  The value 0 is being interpreted as NULL pointer which is why NULL is being printed.  Use `%d` to print integers:

```
printf("TRAVELS_COUNT: %d\n", clientes[i].totalViajes);
```

Second, when you go to `free` the strings for the deleted element, you're deleting the wrong one.  You're using index `totalClientes`, which is off the end of the array.  Reading past the end of the array, as well as attempting to `free` memory that wasn't received from `malloc`, invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You presumably wanted to do this for the last element, which has index `totalClientes-1`, but that's not correct either, since that contains the strings for the last element in the list.  The pointers to the memory you wanted to remove are in index `posCliente`, which you overwrite when moving the element, causing a memory leak.  Move the calls to `free` to before the loop that shifts the elements, and use `posCliente` as the index to clean up:

```
// Remove / free memory of the element deleted
free(clientes[posCliente].dni);
free(clientes[posCliente].nombre);
free(clientes[posCliente].apellidos);
free(clientes[posCliente].direccion);

// Rewind one position array clientes since cliente we want to remove
for (i = posCliente; i < totalClientes-1; i++) {
    // Rewind one element array clientes
    clientes[i] = clientes[i+1];
}
```

Finally, you can't call `free` on the last element of the array, since 1) it's not a pointer, and 2) even if you took its address, that address wasn't returned by `malloc`.  The `realloc` you have commented out is fine.  The reason it crashed was due to undefined behavior that appeared earlier in your program.

Also, `fflush(stdin)` is not valid, and [`gets` is insecure and should not be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) because it could allow you to overrun your buffers.  Use `scanf` instead with length modifiers to specify the maximum size:

```
    printf("Input NIF: ");
    scanf("%254s", dni);
    printf("Input NAME: ");
    scanf("%254s", nombre);
    printf("Input SURNAME: ");
    scanf("%254s", apellidos);
    printf("Input ADDRESS: ");
    scanf("%254s", direccion);
```

Comment: Ok, thank you so much!! When I changed free lines up, problem was solved, both things works fine! I am so grateful. Also, your information is so good to, I will take it in care for change proyect! Thank you, again :). I have one question: If I put ´free´'s lines after totalClientes++; this works fine too right? (it must delete last item of `clientes`). I have tryed it, and it does not give error. But last element if I print it, continues existing, is not deleted

Comment: @JuMoGar Dereferencing pointers that have already been free'ed is undefined behavior.  The physical data *might* still be there, but there's no guarantee.

Comment: Oh, ok, thank you!. Then, It is correct too do: totalClientes--; and after free's?

Comment: @JuMoGar Yes, but then you'll have to adjust the loop which moves everything one position if you put `totalClientes--` before the loop.